# Generate random number sequence with certain entropy

Tags: c++, random, entropy

I need to generate partly random sequence of numbers such that the sequence overall has certain entropy level.

E.g. if I would feed the generated data into gzip it would be able compress it. And in fact, this would be the exact application for the code, testing data compressors.

I'm programming this in C++ and first idea that came into my mind would be to initialize bunch of std::mt19937 PRNGs with random seed and choose one randomly  and make random lenght pattern with it.
The std::mt19937 is reset each time with same seed so that it always generates same pattern:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::random_device rd;
    std::vector<std::mt19937> rngs;
    std::vector<int> seeds;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> patternrg(0,31);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> lenghtrg(1,64);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> valuerg(0,255);

    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        seeds.push_back(rd());
        rngs.emplace_back(seeds.back());
    }

    for(;;) {
        // Choose generator and pattern lenght randomly.
        auto gen = patternrg(rd);
        auto len = lenghtrg(rd);
        rngs[gen].seed(seeds[gen]);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            std::cout << valuerg( rngs[gen] )<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Above code mets the first requirement of generating compressable randomness but the second is harder: how to control the level entropy/randomness?

Comment: How about each byte either repeats the previous byte with probability `p` or is random with probability `(1-p)`

Comment: There are many *kinds* of random sequences with a given entropy rate.  The simplest and most general might not be helpful for compression testing; would you like to hear about them anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I would be glad to hear about those. The example code I gave is actually pretty good, since it makes random substrings but I have no idea how to control the entropy rate for that.

Comment: I would suggest testing it with real files, instead of semi-random sequences which are not relevant to real files who have a certain structure to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write few sentences which you could find useful. Suppose we want to sample one bit with given entropy. So it is either 0 or 1, and entropy you want is equal to `e`.

H(10|p) = -p log<sub>2</sub>(p) - (1 - p) log<sub>2</sub>(1 - p), where `p` is probability to get 1. Simple test - in case of p=1/2 one would get entropy of 1 - maximum entropy. So you
pick `e` equal to some value below 1, solve equation

-p log<sub>2</sub>(p) - (1 - p) log<sub>2</sub>(1 - p) = e

and get back `p`, and then you could start sampling using [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). Simple demo is [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EntropyOfAMessageUsingRandomVariables/). And in C++ one could use standard [library routine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution).

Ok, suppose you want to sample one byte with given entropy. It has 256 values, and entropy

H(byte|\vec{p}) = -Sum(1...256) p<sub>i</sub> log<sub>2</sub>(p<sub>i</sub>).

Again, if all combination are equiprobable (p<sub>i</sub>=1/256), you'll get -256/256 log<sub>2</sub>(1/256) = 8, which is maximum entropy. If you now fix your entropy (say, I want it to be 7), then there would be infinite number of solutions for p<sub>i</sub>, there is no single unique realization of given entropy.

You could simplify problem a bit - lets consider again one parameter case, where probability to find `1` is `p` and probability to find `0` is (1-p). Thus, from 256 outcomes we now got 9 of them - 00000000, 00000001, 00000011, 00000111, 00001111, 00011111, 00111111, 01111111, 11111111.
For each of those cases we could write probability, compute entropy, assign it to whatever you want and solve back to find `p`.

Sampling would be relatively easy - first step would be sample on of the 9 combinations via [discrete distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/discrete_distribution/), and second step would be shuffle bits inside the byte using [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Same approach might be used for, say, 32bits or 64bits - you have 33 or 65 cases, construct entropy, assign to whatever you want, find `p`, sample one of them and then
shuffle bits inside sampled value.

No code right now, but I could probably write some code later if there is an interest...

UPDATE

Keep in mind another peculiar property of the fixing entropy. Even for a simple case of single bit, if you try to solve

-p log<sub>2</sub>(p) - (1 - p) log<sub>2</sub>(1 - p) = e

for a given `e`, you'll get two answers, and it is easy to understand why - equation is symmetric wrt `p` and `1-p` (or replacing 0s with 1s and 1s with 0s). In other words, for entropy it is irrelevant if you transfer information using mostly zeros, or mostly ones. It is not true for things like natural text.

Comment: Thanks for the theory part!
I have to admit this rabit hole got *way* deeper than I tought!

Comment: @JATothrim You're welcome. Looks like problem is defining entropy is necessary condition but not sufficient to get distribution you want.

Answer (score 0):

The **entropy rate** (in terms of the output *byte* values, not the human-readable characters) of your construction has several complications, but (for a number of generators much smaller than 256) it’s a good approximation to say that it’s the entropy of **each choice** (5 bits to pick the sequence plus 6 for its length) divided by the **average length** of the subsequences (65/2), or 0.338 bits out of a possible 8 per byte.  (This is significantly lower than normal English text.)  You can increase the entropy rate by defining **more sequences** or **reducing the typical length** of the subsequence drawn from each.  (If the subsequence is often just one character, or the sequences number in the hundreds, collisions will necessarily reduce the entropy rate below this estimate and limit it to 8 bits per byte.)

Another easily tunable sequence class involves drawing **single** bytes from [0,*n*] with a probability *p*<1/(*n*+1) for 0 and the others equally likely.  This gives an entropy rate *H*=(1-*p*)ln (*n*/(1-*p*))-*p* ln *p* which lies on [ln *n*,ln (*n*+1)), so **any desired rate** can be selected by choosing *n* and then *p* appropriately.  (Remember to use lg instead of ln if you want *bits* of entropy.)